# Execution order of a single signal connected to a single slot via Qt::QueuedConnection

Tags: qt

Assume object `A` (living in `aThread`), and object `B` (living in `bThread`).
Assume further, `A.signalA(int)` is connected to `B.slotB(int)` with a `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Now signalA is subsequently emitted:

```
emit signalA(1);
emit signalA(2);
emit signalA(3);
```

Will `slotB` be executed/called in order of signal reception - and thus **always** result in slotB being called in the order 1,2,3? If no, under which circumstances?

The term "queued" suggests that there is a queue with an order applied, and this would also be intuitive, but I failed to find confirmation in the documentation beyond the name.

This questions is different from [Signal execution order with Qt::QueuedConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188152/signal-execution-order-with-qtqueuedconnection) which refers to two signals being connected to two different slots.

Comment: You can treat signals as normal function calls so yes, it's not reordered.

Comment: According to documentation "The slot is executed in the receiver's thread". Do if you guarantee that signals are emitted in order you need, they must be operated in the same order receiver's thread. There is also [an example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) in official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of  Qt::QueuedConnection, signal events are stored in a FIFO. It basically a priority queue, where events are stored based on their priority.

The implementation(from https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15.2/src/corelib/thread/qthread_p.h#L124)  is

```
// This class holds the list of posted events.
//  The list has to be kept sorted by priority
class QPostEventList : public QVector<QPostEvent>
{
public:
    // other implementation
    void addEvent(const QPostEvent &ev) {
        int priority = ev.priority;
        if (isEmpty() ||
            constLast().priority >= priority ||
            insertionOffset >= size()) {
            // optimization: we can simply append if the last event in
            // the queue has higher or equal priority
            append(ev);
        } else {
            // insert event in descending priority order, using upper
            // bound for a given priority (to ensure proper ordering
            // of events with the same priority)
            QPostEventList::iterator at = std::upper_bound(begin() + insertionOffset, end(), ev);
            insert(at, ev);
        }
    }
};
```

So, the receiving thread event loop will fetch events one by one from the queue. The receiving thread will get the signals in the emission order.

However, it's not good to depend on the order of signal emission. Signals are not events and should not have a temporal dependency.

Comment: Are there instances where a signal event might have a higher priority than others?

Comment: "It's not good to depend on the order ..." Could you elaborate on that? If they are delivered in-order, why should one not do this? Consider f.ex. a use case with a stream of data that can be processed by different threads and you are sending the data frames with signals to each other?

Comment: Signals are notifications that something happened(like the user clicked or data arrived).  How do you order such things ? If you want an order, you build a state machine.

Comment: @Joma There are some events that are of low priority like DelayedDeletion(generated during delete later()), but all signals are of equal priority.

Comment: consider "something happened" being "camera recorded a new frame". Then the frame is sent to processing with a signal. I'd rather have them processed in the correct order ... Also for user events - order might matter quite much as the outcome of f.ex. a button press might depend on other changes before ...